# MariaDB replication for master to slave

Tags: centos, mariadb

After doing some research around this topic, I should be attempting this task soon. However, I have two questions going around my head - could do with an experienced professional answering them.

I am using MariaDB 10.3 and the latest version of Centos 7.

Q1. From the MySQL console, when granting user permission rights, you would grant these for the Private IP and not the Public IP?

Q2. Currently, root permissions are disabled for remote sign-in. Is it a good practise to create a slave user instead and don’t touch root user permissions?

Thank you all!

Comment: Yes and yes. May get more responses over on [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/).

Comment: Thank you, @Dave - much appreciated!

Comment: Voting to close; dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226069/mariadb-replication-from-master-to-slave